# Doctrine2 ODM Limit doesn't work / mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to skip and limit results, but I don't even get it to limit the results.

here's my code

```
    $limit=5;
    $fooQueryBuilder = $this->mongo->getManager()->createQueryBuilder('CustomCoreBundle:Foo');
    $foos=$fooQueryBuilder->limit($limit)->getQuery()->execute();

    var_dump(count($foos));
    exit;
```

and the var_dump returns

```
int(321235)
```

and that's equal to all entities in the database, what am I doing wrong ?

```
$this->mongo->getManager()
```

is instance of

```
Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager
```

and the builder is instance of

```
Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Query\Builder"
```

I just don't understand what's wrong, thanks for any hint

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, I found out the answer myself

```
it is working !
```

and I learned:

when you count() a cursor, no matter what the query, it returns the amount of all entities in database.

So my check to count the cursor to see if the limit is working was simply wrong

Comment: This is a priceless little snippet, glad it's at the top of Google! Should be much clearer in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

use count($result->toArray()) that solved my issue

```
count($result->toArray())
```

Comment: Whilst this works I would caution people about crystallizing the results into an array just to count them, could be better memory wise to keep a count of rows when looping over the results using the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$result->count($foundOnly = true)`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I think it is self explanatory :)

Comment: What is the point of having`$foundOnly` variable in your "self-explanatory" answer then?!

Comment: @ShahriyarImanov it is just a flag which by default is false. $foundOnly is not defined anywhere, just passed that way to clear the meaning of the flag. Is it clear enough now?